# Access an element of a list in the same manner how you access an element of a matrix

Tags: r, list

I have  a matrix:

```r
mat <- matrix(c(3,9,5,1,-2,8), nrow = 2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5   -2
[2,]    9    1    8
```

I have a list:

```r
lst <- as.list(data.frame(matrix(c(3,9,5,1,-2,8), nrow = 2)))

$X1
[1] 3 9

$X2
[1] 5 1

$X3
[1] -2  8
```

I can access my matrix by `mat[i,j]`
I can access my list `lst[[c(i,j)]]`

But if in a matrix if I do `mat[1,2]` I get a 5. If I use same numbers in a list `lst[[c(1,2)]]` I get 9.

Is there a way I can get the same numbers when I access a list? Maybe manipulate the list in certain manner? When I use `lst[[c(1,2)]]` I want to get `5` instead of `9`.I want to get the same numbers I get when using `mat[i,j]`.

Comment: The way you have constructed your list flips the rows and columns - so switch `i` and `j`. Also better not to call an object `list` in R - you can see on SO it is highlighted as it's a reserved word.

Comment: The first index of a matrix is the row but the first index of a data frame is the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transpose()` from `purrr` to transpose a list.

```r
lst2 <- purrr::transpose(lst)

lst2[[c(1,2)]]
# [1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
> list2DF(lst)[1, 2]
[1] 5
```